# Crash on UITapGestureRecognizer Singletap

Tags: ios, crash, uitapgesturerecognizer

This is how my ViewController looks -

```
#import "DialogViewController.h"



 @interface DialogViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation DialogViewController

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
         // Custom initialization
     }
     return self;
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

      UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                           initWithTarget:self
                                                           action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
     [singleTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];}

 - (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
     NSLog (@"Tap");
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 @end
```

This is instantiated and shown from another view using -

```
 DialogViewController *dialogViewController = [[DialogViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DialogViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.parentViewController.view addSubview: dialogViewController.view];
```

If I do a single tap, my app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS. My view doesn't have anything fancy, it just has one single image which is being displayed correctly. I am new to iOS development and am sure that I am doing something silly over here. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to keep a reference to dialogViewController somewhere otherwise it'll be released once its view has been added to the parentViewController

Comment: Which line does the app crash on?

Comment: @chedabob yeah that was the problem. If I make dialogViewController as a property and it works fine

Comment: @duci9y - I got the solution. But, it was crashing in main.

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` comes when memory gets deallocated and code tries to access invalid memory.Little more code will help as how you are allocating your view controller.But i think you should check your view controller it gets deallocated some how.

Maintain a strong reference to the view Controller as your view Controller is deallocating from sowhere and when you `tap` it not finds the pointer.

Answer (score -2):

Try self.view.window

```
[self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
```